# R shiny create filename (string) from selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I want to select different csv files present in a directory with `filenames<-list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")`

but I would like to construct the filename by concatenating two user inputs. As the data files are named $torre$tipo, is it possible to create a string by pasting two inputs from ui.R? I have tried the following code (and some more options) but without success.

```
  filename=renderText({
    paste0(input$torre,input$tipo)
    })

    datos=reactive({
    read.csv(filename,header=T, sep=",",na.strings="-99.9")
  })
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to save your filename as a string with `filename=paste(input$torre, input$tipo, sep="")`. Note the additional `sep` option which has the default value `" "` (In default case the pasted strings are separated by a space).

To use it with Shiny, it needs to be converted to a reactive expression:

```
filename <- reactive ({
    paste(input$torre, input$tipo, sep="")
    })
```

This reactive can then be used in further functions

```
datos <- reactive ({
    read.csv(filename(),...)
    })
```

Comment: I was missing () in read.csv command, stupid mistake. Thanks @drendor